# Get coordinates of geom_hline interception

Tags: coordinates, geom-hline

Is it possible to get the coordinates of the intersection of geom_hline in ggplot from the plot? The image below has a geom_hlline meeting with my line plot but I am hoping to get an exact x-value of the intercept. Please help.
[ggplot with geom_hline shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI3ha.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the data used to plot the graph; paste the output of `dput(your_dataframe)` into the question and the code used to create the graph; [Useful guidance for a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.